# How would I be able to delete certain parts of stdout before displaying

Tags: json, bash

I have this little cli one-liner that I made which displays corporate BS that one typically hears in the workplace.  It is called corporate-bs.  The one-liner is as follows -

```
links -dump https://corporatebs-generator.sameerkumar.website
```

Here is a sample output -

```
{"phrase":"Collaboratively Leverage Other's Corporate Collaboration And Idea-sharing"}
```

Is there any way that I can get rid of the word `phrase`, the brackets(`{}`), and the quotation marks before it gets displayed.
I would like for it to simply display like this -

```
Collaboratively Leverage Other's Corporate Collaboration And Idea-sharing
```

If anyone could help me out with this, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like JSON. Use jq

```
links -dump whatever | jq -r .phrase
```